# .NET URI: How can I change ONE part of a URI?

Tags: c#, .net, url-rewriting

Often I want to change just *one* part of a URI and get a new URI object back.

In my current dilemma, I want to append `.nyud.net`, to use the CoralCDN.

I have a fully qualified URI `fullUri`.  How can I, in effect, do this:

```
fullUri.Host = fullUri.Host + ".nyud.net";
```

This needs to work for almost any URL, and the PORT of the request needs to be maintained.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use an [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) to modify individual parts of an [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163191/");

UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
builder.Host += ".nyud.net";

Uri result = builder.Uri;
// result is "http://stackoverflow.com.nyud.net/questions/2163191/"
```

Comment: How could I be so stupid?  I had no idea that that existed.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry. It's 2019 now and I still had no idea :)

Comment: Don't worry. It's 2027 and AlphaCode 2.1 does all this for you.